# How to connect two docker containers into one python app?

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I have a python (Streamlit) app, which after the installment of all of the packages, is more than 2GB, when 1.8 of its is only the enviroment.

I want to split it into 2 containers.
First container for the Enviroment, which will include of all of the libraries and so on.
The second one will contain only the python app.

Is there any place I can see how can I do that? Can I "inject" the app files into the enviroment somehow alternatively? Or to link the Containers somehow?

Not sure how to start doing this.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to do this?  If you're just worried about the size of the image as it's copied across the network and the time to rebuild it, Docker's image-layer system addresses a lot of these concerns without doing anything special.

Comment: Can't build it on the client side (They have no internet connection due to security concenrs.)

And they say that too big of a file takes too much time to scan or something like that.